# How to improve perfomance of VFP application using SQL as Backend

Tags: sql, indexing, visual-foxpro

I  am having the vfp application and its very complex . I am using the SQL as database , Application responding very late in some scenarios.

How to improve Performance in VFP application ?

Any tips?

Comment: SQL is a language, not a database.

Comment: Show us the portion of code that's problems. It's simply impossible to provide suggestions without some concrete problem at hand.

Comment: In general, the answer is to make sure that you only request the records you need and the fields you need in those records at once. Except for small look-up tables, don't ever request a whole table from the database at once.

Comment: You can also look to tune the SQL server by adding indexes and looking at which queries are taking the longest

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to consider;

Firstly when you run your query in a tool such as SQL Server Management tool, how long does the query take to run?

If it takes 5 minutes to run, then it will take a minimum of 5 minutes to get your data back.

Secondly, if the data you are retrieving is large, then this data has to be transferred from SQL to VFP before you can do anything.

Not much else can be said without an example.